# Open a tab on click of link

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I have a link on a page which when clicked should open the content in a new tab. How should I do this?

Comment: you could do something like window.open("some_page.html#someTab", ""); with some js code fetch the hash value and open the tab..

Comment: @Sudhir:
I think i did not frame the ques properly.. When I say "tab" what I mean is I have created tabs on a page for differetn sections of data.. I want to open that particular tab

Comment: is "tab" means different "Div" in same page?

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to load page on new tab.Try hyperlink with target new like this :

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_new">Open google on new tab</a>
```